# jQuery String Part Replacement

Tags: jquery, wordpress, string, substring

Howdy -- Long time reader, first time questioner. :)

I could really use some assistance replacing part of a string in jQuery 1.5.2.

Loaded into a variable will be this string:

```
<div class="reply">
<a class="comment-reply-link" href="http://someurl/foo/testing-post-four/?replytocom=5#respond" onclick='return addComment.moveForm("comment-5", "5", "respond", "8")'>Reply</a>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the string won't be as clean as this. WordPress generates it, which means the HTML will contain an absurd number of extra spaces and tabs. The comment value will fluctuate.

I'm looking to replace the bit "comment-5" with another string variable - one that will likely be along the lines of `comment-12345` -- no quotes, as it will be pulled from the ID of a neighboring DIV.

Thoughts?

Thanks for the brain power!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to simply use javascripts inbuilt replace function?

```
string.replace('comment-5', 'comment-12345)
```

Or are you reffering to how you can replace the ID? In which case

```
$("#comment-5").attr('id', 'comment-12345');
```

Comment: Hi Craig. Pretend that entire long DIV code block up there is in a variable. I won't know what the comment # is inside it (just pulling the raw HTML code there), but I'd like to replace 'comment-5' (in this example) with another number, also stored in a variable.

Comment: theHTMLCodeFromAbove = theHTMLCodeFromAbove.replace('comment-5', youvariablethatisstored);

Comment: Ah, but I won't know the value 'comment-5' -- I'll need to replace for unknown comment-xxxx :)

Comment: theHTMLCodeFromAbove  = theHTMLCodeFromAbove.replace(/comment\-(\d+)/g, 'comment-' + newValue);

Comment: Neat! My regex is a little rusty. Is this interpretation correct? / » start of expression; \- » escaping the hyphen; () » group; \d » digit 0 - 9; + » one or more preceding term; /g » global;

Comment: They have a desktop version that sits in my quicklaunch.